# How to create SEO Friendly Urls in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, phpstorm

So excited as I have just started working on Laravel, After working nearly for an year with Plain PHP, I finally Started with a framework.

Friends can you please help me with some of my doubts,,,

- I am using Ubuntu as Operating System.
- I am using PhpStorm as IDE.
- I downloaded Laravel Framework and integrated it in PhpStorm.
- I successfully Localhosted laravel Welcome page as localhost/public/index.php

Have done this much so far.. But there is something remaining, the url should be friendly like( localhost/index or localhost/welcome ) but i have to type them fully as ( localhost/public/index.php ).

What is the problem? What am I lacking.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to use /public/index.php

You should setup your webserver (apache/nginx) to use your /public folder as a web root. A typical Laravel installation will take care of the rest if you're using Apache.

See the "Pretty URLs" section of the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation